# Can't show data from JSON to UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, newsapi

I am making a news app, with the use of News API, where it shows the top news of the day at the app's main screen. I created a `UITableView` to store the photos and the titles of the articles but neither of them are appearing correctly.

The code bellow is how I fetch the data and store the properties of the cells in an array called `topNewsArray`, containing the cells properties inside structs named `CellArticle`. If there is no image to store, it will display a newspaper icon provided by SF Symbols.

```
func getTopNews() {
        
        currentLocation = Locale.current.regionCode?.lowercased() ?? "us"
        let urlString: String = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=\(currentLocation)&apiKey=\(apiKey)"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        
        // Check if url is available.
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        // Create URLSession to download and upload data.
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        // Create a task that retrieves the contents of the specified URL.
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            
            // Check for errors.
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                
                // Parse JSON.
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                    
                    let topNewsFeed = try decoder.decode(NewsFeed.self, from: data!)
                    let topNewsCount: Int = (topNewsFeed.articles?.count)!
                    
                    // Add news to the topNewsArray.
                    for i in 0..<topNewsCount {
                        
                        let cellTitle = topNewsFeed.articles?[i].title
                        
                        if topNewsFeed.articles?[i].urlToImage != nil {
                            let cellImage = topNewsFeed.articles?[i].urlToImage
                            self.topNewsArray.append(CellArticle(title: cellTitle, imageName: cellImage))
                        }
                        else {
                            self.topNewsArray.append(CellArticle(title: cellTitle, imageName: "newspaper"))
                        }
                        print("News Title: ", cellTitle!, "\n")
                        
                    }
                }
                
                catch {
                    print("Error in JSON Parsing.")
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Make the API Call.
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
```

The message from the `print("News Title: ", cellTitle!, "\n")` does work, showing all the top news of the day.

So I think the problem is at the `tableView` function, where I typed the following code to populate it with the cells containing the data from their respective `CellArticle`from the `topNewsArray`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let currentArticle = topNewsArray[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        
        cell.label.text = currentArticle.title
        
        if currentArticle.imageName == "newspaper" {
            cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "newspaper")
        }
        else {
            let urlToImage = URL(string: currentArticle.imageName!)
            let dataImage = try? Data(contentsOf: urlToImage!)
            cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(data: dataImage!)
        }
        
        
        return cell
    }
```

The result I expected is something like this at the Main storyboard:

[image]

But I am getting an empty table, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, just needed to put this code after the for loop

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.table.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add this in your **for loop**:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

where **tableView** will be the name of your table view.